# Let $W ∼ Uniform[1, 4]$. Compute each of the following. (a) $P(W ≥ 5)$

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Let $W ∼ Uniform[1, 4]$. Compute each of the following.

$(a) P(W ≥ 5)$

$$P(W \geq 5) = 1 - P(W < 5)$$

$$=1 - \frac{5-1}{4-1} = 1-\frac{4}{3} = -\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer is $0$. Why? Could someone explain?

Comment: So, negative probability does not bell?

Comment: You used $\frac{5-1}{4-1}=P(W\lt 5)$.  It is obviously wrong, since $P(W\lt 5)=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of random variable uniformly distributed on $[1,4]$, $W$ can get **any** value **between** $1$ and $4$. It is impossible for $W$ to fall outside the interval $[1, 4]$. Therefore, the probability, it got a value larger than $5$, is strictly **zero**.